# Error compiling beamer class

Tags: beamer

I have started to use the beamer class but it wont compile.
Just with:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{default}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

It doesn't compile, it says that:

> "Default Compiler: PDfLatex:  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "template_Beamer".tex" could not be iniciated.

Template_beamer.tex is the name of my archive. I don't know where the problem is, I've read something about the problem but maybe is the MiKTeX 2.9 version that doesn't work alright with the beamer class?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your package default.sty stands for something ? Do you have the same problem with the article class? Which editor are you using ?

Comment: @sztruks my editor is textudio and it doesnt happen with the article class. Im not sure about your first question, if my package defoult.sty stands for something.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this with a full installation of the current MikTex 2.9 on a fully updated Windows 10 system.  My IDE is the current version of texmaker. default does not exist as a package, so either delete or reference an existing package.   And second you need to have some actual content for the compiler to produce output.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{default}
\begin{document}
\frame{hello}
\end{document}
```

and the output is just the word "hello" on a blank screen.

You error message seems to imply that you installed your IDE before you installed MikTeX.  You need to either set the paths manually in your IDE or you need to reinstall the IDE after you have installed MikTeX.  You must do both, first MikTeX and then the IDE.